# How do I refresh/update QLabel with data from USB serial (from Arduino)?

Tags: python, arduino, pyqt, pyqt4, pyserial

I know this is a NOOB question; forgive me. I built a Pinewood Derby race timer (small car track) for Cub Scouts using a combination of an Arduino to control timing and RasPi for GUI display of lane place (1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc.) and run time in seconds (e.g. "2.1234"). I have the basic shell GUI setup in QT Creator and have successfully connected the Arduino & RasPi via USB. I am also successfully pulling the Arduino serial data into RasPi (tested with separate small Python code).

Problem I am having is the dynamic update of the QLabels in the GUI once the Arduino fires the race result strings via USB. in other words, when a race starts the Arduino sends "B" for begin (need GUI to blank previous results); when race is finished, Arduino sends "F" and then sends place "1" along with time "2.1234" and I need Python to update/change respective QLabels for each lane place and lane time. I am sure there is an easy way to do this, but I am unable to find how via searching this awesome website and others.

Thanks much in advance and I apologize for what is probably FUBAR coding that follows! The sample below only shows one lane vs. the 4x lanes I will use once I figure out how to do this.

There **two Python codes** I am working with:

**Python code to interface with QT Creator generated XML code**:

```
import sys
import time
import serial

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic

global ser

ser=serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB1",115200)
ser.flushInput()

qtCreatorFile = "PinewoodDisplay.ui" # Enter file here.

Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

class MyApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        Ui_MainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

while True:
    if ser.inWaiting()>0:
        inputValue = (ser.readline().strip())
        self.Lane1_Place.setText(inputValue)
```

**XML generated from QT Creator (not sure if I am posting this right) -- filename is "PinewoodDisplay.ui":**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>619</width>
    <height>1051</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">background-color: rgb(102, 102, 108)</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="QGroupBox" name="Lane1_Group">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>50</x>
      <y>20</y>
      <width>481</width>
      <height>741</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="cursor">
     <cursorShape>CrossCursor</cursorShape>
    </property>
    <property name="autoFillBackground">
     <bool>false</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">background-color : rgb(0, 75, 0)</string>
    </property>
    <property name="title">
     <string/>
    </property>
    <property name="alignment">
     <set>Qt::AlignHCenter|Qt::AlignTop</set>
    </property>
    <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
     <item row="2" column="0">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="Lane1_Place">
       <property name="sizePolicy">
        <sizepolicy hsizetype="Expanding" vsizetype="Expanding">
         <horstretch>0</horstretch>
         <verstretch>0</verstretch>
        </sizepolicy>
       </property>
       <property name="palette">
        <palette>
         <active>
          <colorrole role="WindowText">
           <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
            <color alpha="255">
             <red>255</red>
             <green>255</green>
             <blue>255</blue>
            </color>
           </brush>
          </colorrole>
          <colorrole role="Button">
           <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
            <color alpha="255">
             <red>0</red>
             <green>75</green>
             <blue>0</blue>
            </color>
           </brush>
          </colorrole>
          <colorrole role="Text">
           <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
            <color alpha="255">
             <red>255</red>
             <green>255</green>
             <blue>255</blue>
            </color>
           </brush>
          </colorrole>
          <colorrole role="ButtonText">
           <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
            <color alpha="255">
             <red>255</red>
             <green>255</green>
             <blue>255</blue>
            </color>
           </brush>
          </colorrole>
          <colorrole role="Base">
           <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
            <color alpha="255">
             <red>0</red>
             <green>75</green>
             <blue>0</blue>
            </color>
           </brush>
          </colorrole>
          <colorrole role="Window">
           <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
            <color alpha="255">
             <red>0</red>
             <green>75</green>
             <blue>0</blue>
            </color>
           </brush>
          </colorrole>
         </active>
         <inactive>
          <colorrole role="WindowText">
           <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
            <color alpha="255">
             <red>255</red>
             <green>255</green>
             <blue>255</blue>
            </color>
           </brush>
          </colorrole>
          <colorrole role="Button">
           <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
            <color alpha="255">
             <red>0</red>
             <green>75</green>
             <blue>0</blue>
            </color>
           </brush>
          </colorrole>
          <colorrole role="Text">
           <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
            <color alpha="255">
             <red>255</red>
             <green>255</green>
             <blue>255</blue>
            </color>
           </brush>
          </colorrole>
          <colorrole role="ButtonText">
           <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
            <color alpha="255">
             <red>255</red>
             <green>255</green>
             <blue>255</blue>
            </color>
           </brush>
          </colorrole>
          <colorrole role="Base">
           <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
            <color alpha="255">
             <red>0</red>
             <green>75</green>
             <blue>0</blue>
            </color>
           </brush>
          </colorrole>
          <colorrole role="Window">
           <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
            <color alpha="255">
             <red>0</red>
             <green>75</green>
             <blue>0</blue>
            </color>
           </brush>
          </colorrole>
         </inactive>
         <disabled>
          <colorrole role="WindowText">
           <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
            <color alpha="255">
             <red>255</red>
             <green>255</green>
             <blue>255</blue>
            </color>
           </brush>
          </colorrole>
          <colorrole role="Button">
           <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
            <color alpha="255">
             <red>0</red>
             <green>75</green>
             <blue>0</blue>
            </color>
           </brush>
          </colorrole>
          <colorrole role="Text">
           <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
            <color alpha="255">
             <red>255</red>
             <green>255</green>
             <blue>255</blue>
            </color>
           </brush>
          </colorrole>
          <colorrole role="ButtonText">
           <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
            <color alpha="255">
             <red>255</red>
             <green>255</green>
             <blue>255</blue>
            </color>
           </brush>
          </colorrole>
          <colorrole role="Base">
           <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
            <color alpha="255">
             <red>0</red>
             <green>75</green>
             <blue>0</blue>
            </color>
           </brush>
          </colorrole>
          <colorrole role="Window">
           <brush brushstyle="SolidPattern">
            <color alpha="255">
             <red>0</red>
             <green>75</green>
             <blue>0</blue>
            </color>
           </brush>
          </colorrole>
         </disabled>
        </palette>
       </property>
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <family>Gentium Book Basic</family>
         <pointsize>350</pointsize>
         <weight>75</weight>
         <bold>true</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="autoFillBackground">
        <bool>false</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">color: rgb(255, 255, 255)</string>
       </property>
       <property name="lineWidth">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>4</string>
       </property>
       <property name="scaledContents">
        <bool>true</bool>
       </property>
       <property name="alignment">
        <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="3" column="0">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="Lane1_Time">
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>90</pointsize>
         <weight>75</weight>
         <bold>true</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">color: rgb(255, 255, 255)</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>4.5678</string>
       </property>
       <property name="alignment">
        <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
     <item row="1" column="0">
      <widget class="QLabel" name="lblLane1">
       <property name="font">
        <font>
         <pointsize>36</pointsize>
         <weight>75</weight>
         <bold>true</bold>
        </font>
       </property>
       <property name="styleSheet">
        <string notr="true">color: rgb(255, 255, 255)</string>
       </property>
       <property name="text">
        <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;span style=&quot; color:#e9e9e9;&quot;&gt;Lane 1&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
       </property>
       <property name="alignment">
        <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
       </property>
      </widget>
     </item>
    </layout>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>619</width>
     <height>27</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
  <action name="actionTest">
   <property name="text">
    <string>test</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blocking tasks such as the while True that you need to read the serial data are not GUI-friendly, so you should not run on the same thread, the appropriate option is to execute them on another thread, and send the necessary information to the main thread by signals.

```
import sys
import serial

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, uic

qtCreatorFile = "PinewoodDisplay.ui"

Ui_MainWindow, QtBaseClass = uic.loadUiType(qtCreatorFile)

class SerialThread(QtCore.QThread):
    dataChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.ser = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB1",115200)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            if self.ser.inWaiting()>0:
                inputValue = self.ser.readline().strip()
                self.dataChanged.emit(inputValue)

class MyApp(QtGui.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)
        thread = SerialThread(self)
        thread.dataChanged.connect(self.Lane1_Place.setText, QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)
        thread.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The same task could be done with `QRunnable` and `QThreadPool`, also to send the data you could use `QMetaObject::invokeMethod()`

Comment: OMG --- It works!! Well, you knew that. Thank you SO much; I can't tell you how much time I spent trying to figure this out. Really appreciate it!